# How do we add quotes to an oracle query in node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am new to node.js and it seems like a simple problem but I have a parametrised variable which I need to put in quotes for the value to appear as it is appering in oracle server.

How do I add this?

Here is the nodejs code:

```
export const orderItemCRQry = async (coil: any) => {
  try {
    const sql = `SELECT    ccl_id_order,    ccl_id_order_item    FROM    v_cold_coil    WHERE    
       ccl_id_coil = :coil_id`;
    const binds = [`${coil}`];
    
    return await query(sql, binds);
   
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error.InternalServerError("Error!");
  }
};
```

This is the query section. I need to put :coil_id in quotes to get a value when I put a static variable like '001300' in quotes it gives the correct value however if I want to put coil id like this ':coil_id' it gives bad request . How do I put quotes there for the parametrised query to work

In oraclesql:

when I run the query:

```
SELECT    ccl_id_order,    ccl_id_order_item    FROM    v_cold_coil    WHERE    
           ccl_id_coil = '001300'
```

like this it works
and If I remove the quotes I get no value. There fore I need to add quotes to the default 001300 value which I am getting . How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes when using bind variables.  The following snippet:

```
    const coil = 'abc';
    const result = await connection.execute(
      `SELECT * FROM DUAL where 'abc' = :coil_id`,
      [`${coil}`]);
    console.dir(result.rows, { depth: null });
```

gives:

```
[ [ 'X' ] ]
```

showing that the WHERE condition was satisfied.